# editing column of a text file

Tags: linux, python, perl, awk

abc.txt consists of two column data as

```
1  A1021
2  A1021
3  A1022
4  A1022
```

I want another test file, say pqr.txt (replacing `A1021` by `1` and `A1022` by `2` and so on).

I used the following usual perl code as

```
open(IN,"abc.txt") or die;
open(OUT,">pqr.txt") or die;
While(<IN>) {
    chomp;
    $curline = $_;
    @data = split(' ',$curline);
    If($data[1] eq A1021) {$data[1] = 1;}
    If ($data[1] eq A1022) {$data[1] = 2;}
}
close(IN)
close(OUT)
```

**How can I do looping if I have a big set of data(say, 500) and discontinuous values** in second column in abc.txt file as

```
1  A1021
2  A1021
3  A1022
4  A1022
5  A1026
6  A1026
```

I am interested to replace `A1021` by `1`, `A1022` by `2` and `A1026` by `3` and so on. Any other suggestions like using awk or python might help me.

Comment: Sorry, I just missed to add the following at coding part as                                                                print OUT "$data[0]\t$data[1]\n";

Answer (score 0):

If you want the outputs to always increment:

(A1021, A1021, A1025, A1029, A1025 = 1, 1, 2, 3, 4)

```
$i = 0;
$last = "";

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    @data = split;
    if ($data[1] ne $last) {
        ++$i;
        $last = $data[1];
    }
    $data[1] = $i;
    print "@data\n";
}
```

If you want the same input to have the same output:

(A1021, A1021, A1025, A1029, A1025 = 1, 1, 2, 3, 2)

```
$i = 0;
%v = ();

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    @data = split;
    $data[1] = $v{$data[1]} //= ++$i;
    print "@data\n";
}
```